# Como usar Select onchange para não mostrar parâmetros na url?

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte select

```
<select onchange="location = options[selectedIndex].value" id="sel">
<option value="?cod=<%=cod%>&op=1">opção 1</option>
<option value="?cod=<%=cod%>&op=2">opção 2</option>
<option value="?cod=<%=cod%>&op=3">opção 3</option>
</select>
```

E na url aparece: site/?cod=x&op=1

**Preciso que o select seja enviado com processamento interno**

**e a url ficar = site/?cod=x**

pode ser com hidden ou js

É possível?
agradeço antecipadamente as respostas

Comment: Já tentou [**Ajax**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) ou [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/History_API)?

Comment: poderia simplesmente usar `this.value` em vez de `options[selectedIndex].value`.

Comment: Tá usando PHP para pegar os valores?

Comment: É Asp e pega na mesma pag pelo cod e reordena o menu com o op=x. DVD: Troquei para onchange="location = this.value" mas continua aparecendo o parâmetro &op=x. Preciso incluir mais algum comando?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, li agora sobre history.pushState, mas infelizmente o pgm em Asp não é html5. Mas me será útil em outro projeto em php e html5. Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: A dica que eu comentei não foi pra resolver o problema, foi apenas para deixar mais simples :D... vou analisar o código...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha sugestão é a seguinte: crie um `span` logo após o `select` (o `span` não interfere em nada no layout da página, será usado apenas para receber um formulário de onde será enviado o valor de `op`). Ficará assim:

```
<select onchange="redir(this.value)" id="sel">
   <option value="?cod=11&op=1">opção 1</option>
   <option value="?cod=21&op=2">opção 2</option>
   <option value="?cod=31&op=3">opção 3</option>
</select>
<span id="tempform"></span>
```

Note que no `onchange` será chamada uma função `redir` passando o valor do `option` selecionado.

Agora insira a função na página:

```
function redir(i){
   // pega o valor do select e separa em grupos cod=X e op=X
   var params = i.match(/\?(.+)&(.+)/);
   // pega cod=X
   var cod = "?"+params[1];
   // pega apenas a parte numérica de op=X
   var op = params[2].match(/\d+/)[0];

   // monta o formulário para ser enviado com o valor de op
   // note que o formulário não aparecerá na página com display: none
   var form = '<form style="display: none;" method="post" action="'+location.href+cod+'">'
   +'<input name="op" value="'+op+'">'
   +'</form>';

   // insere o formulário no span
   document.getElementById("tempform").innerHTML = form;
   // faz o submit do formulário
   document.querySelector("#tempform form").submit();
}
```

Ao disparar o `onchange` do `select`, a página será redirecionada para si mesma desta forma:

```
pagina.asp?cod=valor_no_option
```

Ao mesmo tempo será submetido o formulário criado pelo script com o campo `op` via POST.

Desta forma você poderá recuperar os valores `cod` e `op` no ASP com:

```
<%
cod = request("cod")
op = request("op")
%>
```

Comment: Excelente solução. No meu caso inibi o var=cod e tirei do var form porque o cod é o mesmo e só troca a opção de menu. Rodou perfeito. Parabéns e muito obrigado!!

Comment: DVD, usei seu modelo tb em outros pgm mas precisei fazer um xunxo com o asp para o regex funcionar. Vc pode ver e opinar? Como eu posto aqui? Incluo em "Responder à sua pergunta",  edito a minha com "Complemento" ou crio uma nova pergunta? (não será considerada duplicada?) Agradeço

Comment: SAM, coloquei com as explicações: jsfiddle.net/Georgeacsl/87vg0upe/15

Comment: Eu vi. Não entendi porque vc colocou código ASP no JavaScript se pode pegar a URL da página apenas com JavaScript mesmo.

Comment: É isto que não consegui, só usar o js com regex para processar as urls sem cod e com cod, O asp foi um jeitinho para funcionar. (no css tem as obs). Pode dar uma dica?

Comment: Esse aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/87vg0upe/19/

Comment: O select ficou sem ação (não roda) Desculpe tomar seu tempo, vamos pra última tentativa. Esta assim https://jsfiddle.net/87vg0upe/23/

Comment: Faltou substituir o `string`por `i`.... fiz alterações tb: https://jsfiddle.net/87vg0upe/28/

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado